# Display an array data in a table

Tags: php

I have an array and i want to display the data in multiple tables.All modules in a specific year and semester should be in a single table.For e.g all module found in `semester_id` 1 and `year 1` should be in a single table

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 1
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => MATH1103C
            [module_name] => Decision Mathematics
            [module_credit] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 1
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => ITE1107C
            [module_name] => Language and Communication Seminar
            [module_credit] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 1
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => MGMT1101C
            [module_name] => Management Seminar
            [module_credit] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 1
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => HCA1105C
            [module_name] => Computer Architecture
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 1
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => PROG1115C
            [module_name] => Object Oriented Software Development I
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 1
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => WAT1116C
            [module_name] => Internet Programming I
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 1
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => MATH1101C
            [module_name] => Analytic Methods for Computing
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 1
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => PROG1116C
            [module_name] => Object Oriented Software Development II
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 1
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => DBT1111C
            [module_name] => Database Design
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 2
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => PROG2117C
            [module_name] => Desktop Application Development
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 2
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => OSS2109C
            [module_name] => Operating Systems
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 2
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => CAN2112C
            [module_name] => Network Design & Programming
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 2
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => WAT2117C
            [module_name] => Internet Programming II
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 2
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => MGMT2104C
            [module_name] => Research & Development Seminar
            [module_credit] => 3
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 2
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => MCT2104C
            [module_name] => Mobile Application Development
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 2
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => WAT2124C
            [module_name] => Web Services
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 2
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => MATH2323C
            [module_name] => Numerical Methods
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 2
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => SDT2114C
            [module_name] => Requirements Engineering
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 3
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => SEM3112C
            [module_name] => Project Management Seminar
            [module_credit] => 3
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 3
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => SECU3119C
            [module_name] => Secure Software Development
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 3
            [semester_id] => 1
            [module_code] => MULT3114C
            [module_name] => Game Development
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 3
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => PROJ3105C
            [module_name] => Systems Development Project
            [module_credit] => 9
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 3
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => MGMT3105C
            [module_name] => Entrepreneurship Seminar
            [module_credit] => 3
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 3
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => SEM3113C
            [module_name] => Software Quality Management
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 3
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => WAT3125C
            [module_name] => Emerging Web Technologies
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [year_id] => 3
            [semester_id] => 2
            [module_code] => SDT3104C
            [module_name] => Enterprise Software Development
            [module_credit] => 4
        )

)
```

Here is my code so far

```
if (isset($rows) && is_array($rows)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {

        /*echo 'Year ID: ' . $rows[$i]['year_id'] . '<br>';
            echo 'Semester ID : ' . $rows[$i]['semester_id'] . '<br>';
            echo 'Module Code' . $rows[$i]['module_code'] . '<br>';*/
        echo <<<HTML
<div class="title">
        <h1>Year {$rows[$i]['year_id']}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="datagrid">

        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Semester {$rows[$i]['semester_id']}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Module Code</th>
                <th>Module Name</th>
                <th>Credits</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{$rows[$i]['module_code']}</td>
                <td>{$rows[$i]['module_name']}</td>
                <td>{$rows[$i]['module_credit']}</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="combo">
                        <option value=""> --Grade-- </option>
                        <option value="A">A</option>
                        <option value="B">B</option>
                        <option value="C">C</option>
                        <option value="D">D</option>
                        <option value="F">F</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="al">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#b3ffb3"><b>S.P.A</b></td>
                <td bgcolor="#4dff4d">data</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>   
HTML;
```

Comment: first design another array's according to semester and year so you can easily access to draw different table for different semester and year.

Comment: It looks as your data was coming from database. A simple approach would be to read filtered data from db and output simple tables.

Comment: @Frayne Konok can you post an answer on how to create the other array from this one

Comment: I can but it takes much time to complete, and i don't have much time now.

Comment: Do you read the array from db?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone query is an INNER JOIN and contain data from multiple table

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the static code outside the for loop (i.e all ).

You must generate dynamic rows only for data coming from database

```
 ie ({$rows[$i]['module_code']})
```

No need to use multiple head or table just create one table, one head, then use  inside tr and then create dynamic  for array data.

```
 <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>                    
                <th>Module Code</th>  
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
           <?php
                 for ($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++){
                ?>
              <tr>                    
                <td><?php echo $rows[$i]['module_code'] ?></td>  
              </tr>
               <?php }  ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

This is for if need to create a single table.
For e.g all module found in semester_id 1 and year 1 should be in a single table. In this case run table in array and put condition for above.
If matched new table else continue with current table

Comment: its not that easy here since query is an INNER JOIN and contain column from different tables

Comment: All data in the array are dynamic , check array.There are multiple year and semester

Comment: For e.g all module found in semester_id 1 and year 1 should be in a single table. In this case run table in array and put condition for above.

Comment: If matched new table else continue with current table.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over a simple query

```
SELECT DISTINCT year_id, semester_id FROM tablename;
```

For each row print the table head and iterate over the rows of another prepared statement

```
SELECT ... FROM yourQuery WHERE year_id = ? AND semester_id = ?;
```

Print table bottom, end while

end while (outer iteration)